# Prove that $T_1 \circ T_2$ and $T_2 \circ T_1$ has same eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T_1:V \to W$ and $T_2:W \to V$ be two nonzero linear maps then prove that $T_1 \circ T_2$ and $T_2 \circ T_1$ has same eigenvalues.

Any idea?

Comment: This is not true as stated, you have to exclude the zero eigenvalue case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** if
$T_1 (T_2 x) = ax$ then
$T_2(T_1 (T_2 x)) = a(T_2x)$. Hence if $a\neq 0$ you have an inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda\neq0$ We show that $\color{red}{I - \lambda AB \text{ is invertible} \Leftrightarrow  I - \lambda BA \text{ is  invertible}}$.

Suppose $I - \lambda AB$ is invertible, then $ 1 + \lambda B (I - \lambda AB)^{-1}A$ is an inverse to $I - \lambda BA$.
Likewise when $I - \lambda BA$ is invertible $ 1 + \lambda A(1-\lambda BA)^{-1}B$ is an inverse for $I - \lambda AB$.

Comment: Assume finite-dimensional to make this equivalent to the "eigenvalue" thing.